# How does the 2D free boson transform under global conformal transformations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Consider the 2D free boson

$$\mathcal{L}=\int d^2 z\ \partial\phi\ \bar{\partial}\phi$$

How does $\hat{\phi}(z)$ transform under a global conformal transformation $\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$? I think that

$$U[\Lambda]\hat{\phi}(z)U^{\dagger}[\Lambda]=\hat{\phi}\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right)$$

However if this were the case then the two-point function

$$M(z,w)=\langle \hat{\phi}(z)\hat{\phi}(w)\rangle$$

would satisfy

$$M\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d},\frac{aw+b}{cw+d}\right)=M(z,w)$$

which the well known two-point function

$$\langle \hat{\phi}(z)\hat{\phi}(w)\rangle=\ln|z-w|^2$$

clearly does not satisfy. Question: what is $U[\Lambda]\hat{\phi}(z)U^{\dagger}[\Lambda]$?

Comment: a free boson transforms as a scalar under conformal transformations

Comment: @Wakabaloola I thought there was no such thing as a free boson field in the QFT, it has operators that map to $\partial \phi$ and $e^{i k \varphi}$ in the classical limit, but there's no quantum mechanical operator that maps to $\phi$. It transforms as a scalar only in the classical theory. In other words, the correlator $\left< \phi \phi \right>$ is just a function, in order to be a Wightman function it needs to satisfy extra properties which it doesn't. P.S. still waiting on your paper on how to compute string scattering amplitudes by summing over the intermediate off-shell states ;)

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov regarding the name ‘free boson’, this is the usual story: it has an IR-divergent 2pt function, so it isn’t free in the usual sense; but it’s pretty standard terminology, and people usually know immediately what one means by it, so (bowing to tradition) i have decided to stick to it. (do you have a suggestion, what would you rather call it?)

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov your 2nd pt: for symmetries i always take the path integral viewpoint, because symmetries are manifest there: you treat them precisely as you would the corresponding classical quantities. and from the path integral viewpoint this free boson certainly transforms as a scalar under reparametrisations and Weyl, (but in NLSM beta function calculations it is sometimes convenient to let it transform non-trivially under Weyl). for composite operators the above still holds, but in addition one must take into account any non-trivial transf induced by the regulator (here normal ordering)

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov your last point: you remembered! :)  it is already published, sorry i forgot to send it to you: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157320304002

Comment: @Wakabaloola the variable that you're integrating over in the path integral definitely transforms like a scalar, but it isn't the quantum field – the quantum field is an operator-valued distribution that can be obtained from correlation functions (path integrals) through Osterwalder-Schrader reconstruction in most cases. In this case, the reconstruction procedure fails due to the logarithmic divergence in the propagator. $\hat{\phi}$ isn't a well-defined operator-valued distribution, so it doesn't make sense to ask about its transformation law.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov this is true, but in the path integral this is just irrelevant, right?

Comment: @Wakabaloola not sure what you mean. It is definitely physically relevant: most of the time the quantum field (operator-valued distribution) transforms the same way as the integration variable, but in some situations it picks up extra factors due to anomalies in the path integral measure which leads to anomalous dimensions. As I’m sure you know this is very much observable and interesting, so I would definitely say that it matters. In this case the situation is even more counterintuitive: the quantum field simply doesn’t exist at all

Comment: @Wakabaloola OP has a hat in $\phi$ so I assumed they were asking about the quantum transformation law, not classical. Which is a very good question

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov to say that something is physically relevant means that observables depend on it, so which observable do you have in mind?

Comment: @Wakabaloola would you also deny that the anomalous beta function of Yang-Mills and asymptotic freedom are physically relevant then?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov no, but it’s only relevant because it has implications for observables.. you still haven’t answered my question :p  (Regarding composite operators and anomalous transformation laws, i already explained above how to extract these by assuming it transforms as a scalar )

Comment: @Wakabaloola were talking about a toy model - the 2d scalar field. It doesn’t have physical implications because the model itself is unphysical. The term “physically interesting” is overloaded in this case and means “mathematically interesting for the purposes of illustrating a point which becomes physically interesting in other theories such as eg QCD”. You ask for an observable, just take the smeared value of the field $\phi$ which is an observable in Wightman QFT, so physically (read mathematically if you wish) interesting.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov do you mean the integrated expectation value of phi?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov ..and on what manifold?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126283/discussion-between-prof-legolasov-and-wakabaloola).

Answer (score 5):

I assume you've read that in the 2D free boson theory, you're "supposed" to work only with operators like $\partial \phi$ and $e^{i\alpha \phi}$, avoiding $\phi$ itself. But if you're trying to consider the more general theory anyway to see what happens, we need to understand why using
\begin{equation}
\phi^\prime(x^\prime) = \left | \frac{\partial x^\prime}{\partial x} \right |^{-\Delta/d} \phi(x), \;\;\;\; (**)
\end{equation}
as described in the last answer, leads to the contradiction $\left < \phi(z) \phi(w) \right > = 1 \neq \log(z - w)$. The reason is that (**) assumes $\phi$ to be an eigenstate of the dilation operator. But since all powers of $\phi$ have dimension zero, this does not come automatically... we need to check if it's true.

It is helpful to define $\mathcal{O}_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} \phi^n$ and start with the Wick-like result
\begin{equation}
\left < \mathcal{O}_n(z) \mathcal{O}_n(w) \right > = \log^n(z - w)
\end{equation}
and hit it with the differential operator that appears in the Ward identity for the generator of dilations. This leads to
\begin{equation}
\left [ z \partial_z + w \partial_w \right ] \left < \mathcal{O}_n(z) \mathcal{O}_n(w) \right > = n \log^{n - 1}(z - w).
\end{equation}
Comparing to equation (2.5) of https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03959 we see that this is compatible with dilations acting on the $\mathcal{O}_n$ according to
\begin{equation}
i[D, \mathcal{O}_n(z)] = \left ( \Delta_n^{\;\;m} + \delta_n^m z \partial_z \right ) \mathcal{O}_m(z)
\end{equation}
as long as the scaling matrix is given by
\begin{equation}
\Delta = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \dots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
The pesky thing about this matrix isn't only that it's not diagonal but that it's not even *diagonalizable*. In fact, these powers of $\phi$ form an indecomposable representation with an infinitely large Jordan block. So their transformation properties all have to be considered together.

In two dimensions especially, these so called *logarithmic CFTs* have been widely studied but usually in cases with finite Jordan blocks. Included in this are models of percolation and systems with quenched disorder as described in https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0847 and other reviews. It is probably possible to go further with analyzing the free boson CFT in this way as well. It's just not going to be found in introductory textbooks.

Comment: Great answer. May I interest you in this related and unanswered question of mine: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231933/extreme-unitary-minimal-models-of-conformal-field-theory

Answer (score -2):

Let's define conformal transformation first in active point of view.

We have $$x\to x'$$ and
$$\phi(x)\to\phi'(x')$$ we also define a functional such that
$$\phi'(x')=\mathcal{F}(\phi(x))$$
So in order to understand better let's see several explicit examples,

Translation:
$$x'=x+a$$
$$\phi'(x')=\phi(x)$$ thus in this case $\mathcal{F}$ is trivial.
Lorentz:
$$x^{'\mu}=\Lambda^{\mu}_\nu x^\nu$$ and
$$\phi'(\Lambda x)=L_\Lambda\phi(x)$$ where $L$ is the representation of Lorentz group. Thus in this case $F$ is $L$.

Now let's return to your case, one can easily show that we have the following identity,
$$\langle\phi(x')\phi(y')\rangle=\langle\mathcal{F}(\phi(x))\mathcal{F}(\phi(y))\rangle$$

so thats how you should transform the correlation functions. The general conformal transformation  for spinless fields is given as,
$$\phi'(x')=|\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}|^{-\Delta/d}\phi(x)$$
where $|\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}|$ is jacobian. This holds if the action is invariant under those transformations.