# Why convention for Heisenberg algebra?

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, commutator, lie-algebra

In C. A. Keller, “Introduction to Vertex Operator Algebras,” 2017. the Heisenberg Lie algebra is presented as a a Lie algebra spanned by vectors $\alpha_n$, with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k$, where the only non-trivial Lie bracket between the generators is $[\alpha_n,\alpha_m]=n\delta_{n+m,0}k$. Defining $\tilde{\alpha}_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|n|}}\alpha_n$, we obtain a new basis for the Lie algebra in which the only non-trivial commutator is $[\tilde{\alpha}_n,\tilde{\alpha}_m]=\text{sign}(n)\delta_{n+m,0}k$. In terms of these there is a clear physical interpretation: for each $n<0$ there a physical mode of our system, with $\tilde{\alpha}_n$ its creation operator and $\tilde{\alpha}_{-n}$ its annihilation operator. Indeed one could write something along the lines of $\tilde{\alpha}_{n}=\tilde{\alpha}_{-n}^\dagger$ and then one has that the only non-trivial commutation relations are
$$[\tilde{\alpha}_{-n},\tilde{\alpha}_{-n}^\dagger]=k.$$

My question is, why is the normalization of the $\alpha_n$'s preferred over that of the $\tilde{\alpha}_n$'s. Are there any physical systems where the $\alpha_n$'s "appear more naturally" than the creation and annihilation operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the convention is to use operators which are Fourier modes of the most basic fields you want to work with. In $d > 2$, the scalar field itself is something we quantize and then we use $a(\textbf{p})$ and $a^\dagger(\textbf{p})$ which obey a commutation relation just like what you proposed.

In 2D, we don't do this because we want the $\alpha_n$ to be modes of $\partial \varphi$ which is much nicer than $\varphi$ itself. As you may know, a free massless boson in two dimensions does not fall into the primary / descendant dichotomy of unitary CFTs. I gave more information about this in [a recent answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/644271).

**Edit**

Perhaps a better answer is that our freedom to redefine $\tilde{\alpha}_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|n|}} \alpha_n$ and still get a "nice" algebra is a peculiarity of the fact that the zero modes are abelian. The general structure that the Heisenberg algebra fits into is that of an *affine Kac-Moody* algebra where the generators obey
\begin{equation}
[J_n^a, J_m^b] = if^{ab}_{\;\;\;c}J_{m+n}^c + k n g^{ab} \delta_{m+n, 0}.
\end{equation}
We therefore get a nonabelian Lie algebra when we restrict to the zero modes. This would not work if we now tried to scale the generators by $\sqrt{|n|}$.

Naively, we could guess that perhaps Heisenberg (which is affine $U(1)$) also fits into a different family of algebras whose commutation relations look just like the above except with $k g^{ab}$ instead of $k n g^{ab}$. However, this is not a valid central extension as can be seen by checking the Jacobi identity.

Comment: I see, from the notation I imagine then that maybe it is not best to think of the $\alpha_n$'s as creation and annihilation operators, but rather as the components of some current? This would make sense from the point of view of the equation $L_0=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}:\alpha_n\alpha_{-n}:$ (see (4.11) and (4.16) here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04074.pdf and (5.12) of Keller)

Comment: Yes... $\partial \varphi$ is indeed a current since shifting $\varphi$ by a holomorphic function is a symmetry of the free boson.